# How can I return the number of rows affected in sqlplus to a shell script?

Tags: oracle, bash, sqlplus

Here is my shell script:

```
# Deletes data from the 'sample' table starting August 30, 2011.
# This is done in stages with a 7 second break every 
# 2 seconds or so to free up the database for other users. 
# The message "Done." will be printed when there are 
# no database entries left to delete.

user="*****"
pass="*****"
while(true); do
    starttime=`date +%s`
    while [[ $((`date +%s` - $starttime)) -lt 2 ]]; do
        sqlplus $user/$pass@//blabla <<EOF
            whenever sqlerror exit 1
            delete from 
                sample
            where
                sampletime >= to_date('08-30-2011','mm-dd-yyyy') and
                rownum <= 2;
            commit;
EOF
        rows = ???
        if [ $rows -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "Done."
        exit 0;
    fi
    done
    sleep 7
done
```

If there is no way to get the number of rows, maybe I can use an error code returned by sqlplus to figure out when to end the script? Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that it is not easier (and without noticeable performance penalty) to just delete the rows you want to delete in one go? I'd even think that the way you want to do it actually uses more resources on the database.

Comment: `sql%rowcount` as @René Nyffenegger has used it, is the way. Use is before commit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `sql%rowcount` which tells you how many rows were affected by the last DML statement.

```
delete from                  
sample             
where                 
sampletime >= to_date('08-30-2011','mm-dd-yyyy') and                 
rownum <= 2;             


if sql%rowcount = 0 then
   dbms_output.put_line('Free');
end if;

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below
Note:-Not tested

```
user="*****" 
pass="*****" 
while(true); 
do     
starttime=`date +%s`     
while [[ $((`date +%s` - $starttime)) -lt 2 ]]; 
do         
  rows=`sqlplus -silent $user/$pass@//blabla << EOF             
  whenever sqlerror exit 1 
  SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF            
    select count(1) from                  
    sample             
    where                 
    sampletime >= to_date('08-30-2011','mm-dd-yyyy') and                 
    rownum <= 2;             

EOF`         

if [ $rows -neq 0] ; 
then 
    sqlplus $user/$pass@//blabla << EOF1  
    delete  from                  
    sample             
    where                 
    sampletime >= to_date('08-30-2011','mm-dd-yyyy') and                 
    rownum <= 2;             
    commit;
EOF1
else        
echo "Done."         
exit 0;     
fi     
done     
sleep 7 
done
```

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger i have changed the shell script accordingly to delete only when rows affected is greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
                    rows=`sqlplus -s ${DB_USER}/${DB_PASSWD}@${DB_SID} <<EOF
                    delete from sample where sampletime >= to_date('08-30-2011','mm-dd-yyyy') and rownum <= 2;
                    commit;
                    exit;
```

EOF`
                fi

```
            echo rows = $rows
```